# reactJs setState change property on object within an array within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I've got a problem again with changing a property on an object inside an array, but this time its an array in an array in an array ...

I've got a problem on changing the preview of the picture.

this has no effect:

```
return {
     ...picture,
     preview: "hallo"
}
```

The full code is:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    stepsData: prevState.stepsData.map(step => {
        if (step.identifier === stepIdentifier) {
            console.log("lkkljk",step)

            step.onChangeContentComponents.map(
                contentComponent => {
                    if (contentComponent.pictures !== null){
                        console.log(contentComponent.pictures);
                        console.log(contentComponent.pictures[0].preview);

                        contentComponent.pictures.map(picture => {
                            return {
                                ...picture,
                                preview: "hallo"
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return contentComponent
                }
            );

            return {
                ...step,
                [targetArray]: newArray,
            }
        }
        return step
    })
}), () => {
    console.log(this.state.stepsData)
});
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution could be

```
let stepsData = [...this.state.stepsData];
    stepsData = stepsData.map(step => {
        if (step.identifier === stepIdentifier) {
            return {
                ...step,
                [targetArray]: newArray,
                onChangeContentComponents: step.onChangeContentComponents.map(contentComponent => {
                        if (contentComponent.pictures !== null) {
                            return {
                                ...contentComponent,
                                pictures: contentComponent.pictures.map(picture => {
                                    console.log(picture)
                                    return {
                                        ...picture,
                                        preview: "hallo"
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        }
                        return contentComponent
                    }
                )
            }
        }
        return step
    });
    this.setState({stepsData: stepsData}, () => {
        console.log(this.state.stepsData)
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `step.onChangeContentComponents.map` call's returning value is not being used anywhere. You would have to change your code to

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    stepsData: prevState.stepsData.map(step => {
        if (step.identifier === stepIdentifier) {
            console.log("lkkljk",step)

            var newStep = step.onChangeContentComponents.map(
                contentComponent => {
                    if (contentComponent.pictures !== null){
                        console.log(contentComponent.pictures);
                        console.log(contentComponent.pictures[0].preview);

                        contentComponent.pictures.map(picture => {
                            return {
                                ...picture,
                                preview: "hallo"
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return contentComponent
                }
            );

            return newStep
        }
        return step
    })
}), () => {
    console.log(this.state.stepsData)
});
```

However I will advise you to not do complex calculations in setState and abstract out the calculations outside like

```
var stepsData = [...this.state.stepsData];
stepsData = stepsData.map(step => {
        if (step.identifier === stepIdentifier) {

            var newStep = step.onChangeContentComponents.map(
                contentComponent => {
                    if (contentComponent.pictures !== null){
                        console.log(contentComponent.pictures);
                        console.log(contentComponent.pictures[0].preview);

                        contentComponent.pictures.map(picture => {
                            return {
                                ...picture,
                                preview: "hallo"
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return contentComponent
                }
            );

            return newStep
        }
        return step
     });

this.setState({stepsData}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.stepsData)
});
```

Comment: thats not working, no I got errors calling the method.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at ProcessStep.render (eval at ./src/frontend/component/processes/processSteps/ProcessStep.js (bundle.js:12154), <anonymous>:116:61)

Comment: where are you getting 
                `[targetArray]: newArray,`

Comment: target array is only a placeholder for a string. it comes as parameter

Comment: now stepsdata is always an object. Problem is only that `contentComponent.pictures.map(picture => {
                            return {
                                ...picture,
                                preview: "hallo"
                            }
                        });` has no effect. 

targetArray is just a property of each step

Comment: sorry stepsdata is an array of objects

Comment: newArray is not undefined. thats al okay. Console.log() shows the data. Problem is the inner part with the `preview: "Hallo"`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) util to solve it.

Earlier this util was included into [react-addons-update](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) module.